# Hive sql pack array based off column

Tags: sql, hive

I have multiple columns listed below:

```
state          sport            size             color        name
florida        football         1                red          Max
nevada         football         1                red          Max
ohio           football         1                red          Max
texas          football         1                red          Max
florida        hockey           1                red          Max
nevada         hockey           1                red          Max
ohio           hockey           1                red          Max
texas          hockey           1                red          Max
florida        tennis           2                green        Max
nevada         tennis           2                green        Max
ohio           tennis           2                green        Max
texas          tennis           2                green        Max
```

Is there a way to combine these into arrays like the desired output below based on one column (in this case Name). Mac the results will have one record, instead of repeating and the records will be contained in an array.

```
state                                   sport
[florida, nevada, ohio,texas]           [football, hockey, tennis]
size                                    color
[1,2]                                   [red, green]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect_set`.

```
select name,collect_set(state),collect_set(sport),collect_set(size),collect_set(color)
from tbl
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use collect_set. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
query:
select collect_set(state), 
collect_set(sport), 
collect_set(size), 
collect_set(color)
from myTable
where name = 'Max';
```